# Why my apps have black screen in Fast App Switcher?

Tags: windows-phone-8

Any ideas why my app would draw a black screen when it's dormant/suspended (user presses window-key, and then long-presses back-key to view all dormant apps)?

It's Directx113D app, and should be very close to the implementations of Marble Maze and Direct3D samples. They show up just fine.

I've done my best to break these two samples in a similar fashion but no luck. Any ideas?

Comment: Is this in the emulator and are you using Direct X feature level > 9.3? http://blogs.msdn.com/b/shawnhar/archive/2012/11/06/beware-of-d3d-feature-level-11-in-the-windows-phone-emulator.aspx

Comment: Thanks for the info, managed to up the FPS of the samples, but didn't help me with the problem in question. :/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, I've got this one solved.

The problem was with alpha. I don't know why, but when the app has the focus, it draws alpha just fine. However, when send to background alpha blending somehow is turned of and alpha for each pixel remains 0. For my blendstate I changed:

```
SrcBlendAlpha = D3D11_BLEND_ZERO 
DestBlendAlpha = D3D11_BLEND_ZERO
```

to

```
SrcBlendAlpha = D3D11_BLEND_ZERO 
DestBlendAlpha = D3D11_BLEND_ONE
```